# convert cmyk images to rgb in folder use shell command

Tags: shell, image-processing

I want to find all CMYK type images in folder and change them to RGB colorspace.. I use this

```
for f in ./*.jpg
do
type=$(identify -format '%[colorspace]' ./$f);
if [ '$type' == 'CMYK' ]
then
echo '$f is CMYK type';
convert ./$f -colorspace CMYK ./$
fi
done
```

Comment: Instead of editing the question, you should leave your own answer.

Comment: P.S. See http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/

Comment: thank you.. I am new for stackoverflow, but you guys are so kind..

Comment: @neouyghur Good job figuring it out. If you have less luck in the future, [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) will automatically point out this and other problems.

Comment: @thatotherguy wow, it will be very helpful..

Answer (score 2):

this is a shell script, for running it you have to install imagemagic.  identify command for checking the colorspace of image, if image is CMYK type we change it to the RGB color space type.
you can also use it for reverse way.

```
  for f in ./*.jpg
    do
    type=$(identify -format '%[colorspace]' ./$f);
    echo $type
    if [ "$type" == "CMYK" ]
    then
    echo '$f is CMYK type'
    convert ./$f -colorspace CMYK ./$
    # convert  ./$f -colorspace CMYK -colorspace RGB ./$f # uncomment this line and comment previous line if previous line is not working.
    else
    echo 'no work'
    fi
    done
```

Comment: Add some explanation please.

Comment: convert ./$f -colorspace CMYK ./$ 
This one was not working for me.

 convert  ./$f -colorspace CMYK -colorspace RGB ./$f
this works fine

added this below

Answer (score 0):

install imagemagick

Convert one image using this code

```
convert image.jpg -colorspace CMYK -colorspace RGB image.jpg
```

for all images in the folder use below code
please note: it will replace the original image

```
 for f in ./*.jpg
do
type=$(identify -format '%[colorspace]' ./$f);
echo $type
if [ "$type" == "CMYK" ]
then
echo '$f is CMYK type'
convert  ./$f -colorspace CMYK -colorspace RGB ./$f
echo $type
else
echo 'no work'
fi
done
```

Reference https://imagemagick.org/script/color-management.php

Comment: Added the explanation
Thanks